# Controller error in CodeIgniter and Doctrine tutorial

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to connect to function world() but I get an error. Do you know what I have to do? There are my first steps with CodeIgniter - I'm doing [this tutorial](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup).

Urls I've tried:

- localhost/nauka/index.php/hello/world
- localhost/nauka/index.php/Hello/world

Error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\nauka\application\controllers\hello.php on line 5

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not a CI user, but usually a controller has some code to bootstrap the framework itself - not seeing that in your screenshot. Double-check your tutorial to ensure you've put the right code in the right place. Aside: when supplying code here, please don't screenshot it; instead, copy and paste the relevant part in, then select it and click the 'code' button, to ensure it is formatted like code.

Comment: Please hyperlink to the tutorial you're following as well, so people can see what you're seeing easily. Don't make your readers work harder to help you `:)`.

Comment: @halfer I`m sure I put correct code but why I have got error? http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup

Comment: As Kai says, that article may be for an older version. Please consider commenting under it, perhaps linking to here, so that other readers aren't stumped with the same problem `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should extend CI_Controller

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

This may be different for older versions but you shouldn't be using versions that don't extend CI_Controller anyhow.

Also, you need the parent::__construct in there

Comment: In general, if your purpose in specifying a constructor is just to call a parent, then don't add it in - the parent will be called automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`class Hello extends CI_Controller`