# Save error in CodeIgniter and Doctrine tutorial

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I would like to save data in Doctrine 2.3 unfortunately I get error also if it`s possible I need good tutorial for this because in my opinion documentation is not useful.

**My last topic:**

[Controller error in CodeIgniter and Doctrine tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656932/controller-error-in-codeigniter-and-doctrine-tutorial)

**Eroor:**

Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::save() in C:\wamp\www\nauka\application\controllers\hello.php on line 19

**Picture with option save:**

[image]

**Model**

[image]

**ripa I make this what you want but I get error:**

Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in C:\wamp\www\nauka\application\controllers\hello.php on line 8

```
<?php
    // system/application/controllers/hello.php

    $this->load->model("user");

    class Hello extends CI_Controller {

            $this->user->setTableDefinition();

        function world() {
            echo "Hello CodeIgniter!";
        }

        function user_test() {

            $u = new User;
            $u->username = 'johndoe';
            $u->password = 'secret';
            $u->first_name = 'John';
            $u->last_name = 'Doe';
            $u->save();

            $u2 = new User;
            $u2->username = 'phprocks';
            $u2->password = 'mypass';
            $u2->first_name = 'Codeigniter';
            $u2->last_name = 'Doctrine';
            $u2->save();

            echo "added 2 users";
                    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Seems you don't extend Doctrine at User, also User has no method such as save.

Comment: @qeremy Could you show example in post?

Comment: Actually, I have never used Doctrine, but mentally you need to extend a class (which has a save method) at User class or need to define save method in User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php



class Hello extends CI_Controller {

        $this->user->setTableDefinition();

    function world() {
        echo "Hello CodeIgniter!";
    }

    function user_test() {

        $this->load->model("user");
        $u["username"] = 'johndoe';
        $u["password"] = 'secret';
        $u["first_name"] = 'John';
        $u["last_name"] = 'Doe';
        $this->user->save($u);



        echo "added 1 users";
                }

    }

?>
```

can get help from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html. see "table of contents" of this link. you will get everything related to codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

in codeigniter all models will be loaded in controller. require_once will not work. first load your model in costructor like `$this->load->model("your model name")`. then call function of model from controller like `$this->model_name->function_name()`

Answer (score 2):

You can save like this:

```
$this->load->model('user');

$this->user->save_User('username','password','first_name','last_name');
```

Model file:

```
class user extends CI_Model {


    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

     function save_User($username,$password,$fName,$lName)  {

          //Save to database
     }
}
```